# Azure VM(Linux) not booting after encryption

Tags: boot, encryption

I am new to linux. I did encryption on a azure linux vm, followed with the steps which azure suggested. I can see the encryption is enabled and the disk is showing encrypted. But I am unable to boot into the OS. There is no CPU usage/Disk operation. Looks like VM is completely down. Anyone please suggest how to check whether the OS is corrupt or not?

Regards
Mydeen

Comment: Maybe you've encrypted your OS volume, instead of data storage? Have you done any backup or snapshot of your volume before encryption?

Comment: Yes the vm has only OS volume. Yes we took backup before encrypting the VM.

Comment: Well, if you've encrypted your OS volume then, in my understanding, it's not possible to boot it anymore because there is nothing in front of it do decrypt it. So you can either create another VM ubuntu and then try to mount your encrypted volume, or simply use your backup.

Comment: We should not encrypt the OS volume in Linux even manually? 

Azure has listed this OS version (Ubuntu 16.04 LTS) in their list. Which we can enable disk encryption on OS as well Data disks.

Comment: It depend on how it's set up. I suspect you've had bootloader encrypted aswell, so nothing was able to boot an encrypted volume.

Comment: Yes we can say OS disk is corrupted(Unable to find kernal). I am going to try on another VM. That also have only OS volume. Azure support team said try we faced issues but it will get success.Should i try?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what your question is, I don't understand this part: "`try we faced issues but it will get success`"

Comment: Sorry about that. The support team suggested to try once, It will get success. Because they faced some issues while doing encryption for some VM's but they were able to fix the issue. Means successfully encrypted the failed ones(OS and Data).

Comment: In general, with azure or aws VM's you're always safe to do anything, as long as you have backup (i.e. snapshots of current OS/data volumes). So if you have this feedback from azure team and also your backups, then you may try again :)

Comment: Thanks for helping!
I have enabled encryption on a test linux vm. There are some pre-requisites prior to encryption, we did check that. It went smooth. Lets see how it goes on in production.

Comment: @Mydeen Do you have some information regarding the pre-requisites? We are struggling getting the encryption on the os disk to work as well.

Comment: Solved it by myself: For some reason you have to have a small data disk as well, and mount that. The second thing is you have to create a special vault key, which can be used as a encryption key. Follow every instructions here: https://docs.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/azure/virtual-machines/linux/encrypt-disks

Comment: Sorry @Hypnobrew for the late response glad you found the fix.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried Linux VM encryption and faced many issues. I made some points before going to enable the disk encryption on Linux VM in Azure.

Disabling encryption on Linux VMs is **only supported for data volumes**. It is not supported on data or OS volumes **if the OS volume has been encrypted**.

If VM is not booting after encryption then only VM restoration option is available. You cannot resolve the issue.

**Before enabling the disk encryption, we have to prepare the some question’s answer.**

1. Have a working backup for the vm which you are going to encrypt it.
2. Make sure that the VM has enough RAM(**minimum 7Gb**) and also enough space in the **OSDisk**.
3. Make sure that the application is stopped prior to the encryption process is started, also make sure that the application remains stopped after a reboot also, as the ADE process will reboot the vm.
4. Make sure that the vm is not accessed by any means being it ssh or winscp or any other tools.
5. Make sure that there is no extension installed in the vm.
6. Make sure that there is no server hardening is done on the vm which is going to encrypted i.e, Kernel Parameter changes, Grub password setting, boot password setting
7. You can monitor the encryption status using the PowerShell or azure cli commands or checking the serial console.
8. if you are using datadisk, make sure that the file system type is ext4 and not xfs, because xfs file system is not supported for single pass encryption
9. Remove the old kernels which are no longer required and regenerate the grub.cfg file. Keep only 3-4 Old Kernels if required.

***Azure Disk Encryption does not work for the following scenarios, features, and technology:***
•   Encrypting basic tier VM or VMs created through the classic VM creation method.
•   Disabling encryption on an OS drive or data drive of a Linux VM when the OS drive is encrypted.
•   Encrypting OS drive for Linux virtual machine scale sets.
•   Encrypting custom images on Linux VMs.
•   Integration with an on-premises key management system.
•   Azure Files (shared file system).
•   Network File System (NFS).
•   Dynamic volumes.

**Azure Disk Encryption prerequisites**
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/security/azure-security-disk-encryption-prerequisites

**Enable Azure Disk Encryption for Linux IaaS VMs**
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/security/azure-security-disk-encryption-linux

**How to encrypt a Linux virtual machine in Azure**
https://docs.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/azure/virtual-machines/linux/encrypt-disks